# No corre Mis Unit Tests, para testear controlador

Tags: c#, test

No se si es porque estoy utilizando MSTestFramework, tengo dotnet core 2.2 como framework,
Revisando en otras [publicaciones](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61240281/4668184) pero al parecer ese no es el problema he cambiado varias veces mi prueba y la deje con un solo método y quedo así:

```
        [TestMethod]
    public void GetAllProducts_ShouldReturnAllProducts()
    {
       //*** este es un list de datos de la clase FiltroBusquedaProductos
       //*** no se como usar Moq :) ;)
        var testFiltroBusquedaProductos = GetTestFiltroBusquedaProductos();
        var controller = new ConsolidadoProductosController();
        foreach (var item in testFiltroBusquedaProductos)
        {

            JsonResult result = controller.GetConsolidadoProductos(item);
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
        }
       
    }
```

Es algo sencillo pero aun me sale una Interrogación en azul

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy algo novato con esto del UnitTest nose si el assert debe estar fuera del foreach o que me hace falta.

Comment: normalmente se usa para evaluar una situación. Siempre tenes que compilar para cualquier cambio